# Install php 5.6 on Amazon EC2 server

Tags: php, amazon-ec2

I have followed the link below to install php version 5.6, but everytime it installs 5.4 I have enabled and installed everything as proposerd in the link but no success. I am running Nginx.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-install-php-5-6-on-centos-7-0-x64
[image]

Comment: Why are you not trying to install PHP 7.4 [**or PHP 8**](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/php/frameworks/drupal/install+php+8+to+centos+7) or PHP 8.1?

Comment: On EC2 I've previously used PHPFarm https://github.com/fpoirotte/phpfarm, but he now suggests using https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/ -- which, after selecting from a few dropdowns, lets you choose the os/flavour you're after.  The Centos 7 options should hopefully work on Amazon Linux 2

Comment: @Martin Because the already written code uses this version, so I have to install it!

Comment: @PaulCrozer - Already tried that one, it shows 5.6 in repo list but tries to install 5.4 :(

Comment: The already written code needs urgently upgrading to run on a supported php version, hopefully that is a priority already being worked on for you

Comment: @ADyson - Yes I understand that but for the time I need 5.6 version :)

Comment: PHPFarm definitely works - I used it earlier this year to (ahem) install PHP5.3 on EC2 (I didn't want to - but if they want to pay me to do it, who am I to complain..!).  It's a bit of a faff because you have to compile PHP etc., but you get there in the end.

Comment: @PaulCrozer - Thanks let me try this one too!